# show data of nested foreach loop in two different Select Tag in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have two Model(Category,Brand) are relate with one to many relation(hasMany) in laravel, Like `category hasMany brands`. now i want to display brand data in one select tag and category model data in another select tag.

- Here is my Controller code

```php
     $category=Category::with('brands')->get();
      return view('product.add')->with('category',$category);
```

- Here is my view blade.

```html
     <div class="form-group">
       <select name="category_id" class="input">
         <option value="">Select Main    Category</option>
           @foreach($category as $category)
         <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
           @endforeach
       </select>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <select name="brand_id" class="input">
           @foreach($brands->brands as $brand)
              <option value="{{$brand->id}}">{{$brand->name}}</option>
           @endforeach
       </select>
     </div>
```

its not working

Comment: What the expected output and whats the current output

Comment: "its not working". Kills me every time.

Comment: can you expand this 3 words "its not working"

Comment: this will not wok you need to make ajax request on change of Category drop-down and append data into brand drop-down .

Comment: it says undefined variable brands

Comment: you need $category->brands

Comment: Well, that error is pretty straightforward: You didn't pass any "brands" variable to the view.

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53551050/laravel-5-6-get-selected-value-from-a-dropdown-to-use-it-in-another

Comment: @madalinivascu i correct may mistake now view is loaded but without brands data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.6: Get selected value from a dropdown to use it in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53551050/laravel-5-6-get-selected-value-from-a-dropdown-to-use-it-in-another)

Comment: in you second loop you miss the varriable which you pass from controller, just write
$category->brands . I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something simple like this:

```html
    <div class="form-group">
       <select name="category_id" class="input">
         <option value="">Select Main    Category</option>
           @foreach($category as $cat)
         <option value="{{$cat>id}}">{{$cat->name}}</option>
           @endforeach
       </select>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <select name="brand_id" class="input">
           @foreach($category as $cat)
           @foreach($cat->brands as $brand)
              <option value="{{$brand->id}}" category="{{$cat->id}}">{{$brand->name}}</option>
           @endforeach
           @endforeach
       </select>
     </div>
```

and you need to show only the brands for the selected option using javascript(jquery)

```js
    $('[name="category_id"]').on('change',function() {
       if($(this).val() != '') {
          $('[name="brand_id"] option').hide();
          $('[name="brand_id"] option[category="'+$(this).val()+'"]').show();
       } else {
           $('[name="brand_id"] option').show();
       }

    });
```

Comment: now displaying this error `Trying to get property 'brands' of non-object`

Comment: doing `$category as $category` you are overriding the same variable, see updated answer

Comment: now all the data in brand table are shown under brand select tag

Comment: only the brands associatet to that category

Comment: yes only brand none other table, i have product table to but i didn't relate them in models yet.

Comment: i don't understand what you are saying, if you don't see a brand it is because you don't have a brand associated to that category

Comment: category and brand are relate to each other with `category hasMany brands` and `brand belongsTo category` in there respective models, and category_id is listed is brand model, now all the brands are displaying in select tag of brand, same with category. but they are not displaying according to selected category in select tag.

Comment: that means that the js isn't working, do you have any console errors?

Comment: Thank you @madalinivascu you are the MAN. code is working every thing is working fine. thank you very much.